# Are mods from level 60 commendation gear freely transferable between slots?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

It seems like, given the incredibly slow rate of getting purple mats from crew skills, it would be faster to farm dailies for the basic commendation to get purple gear for both me and my main companion.  The issue is I like the way my gear looks and, until I get set bonus gear, I don't plan on replacing it.

Are the mods from the commendation gear freely transferable? And by that, I mean, for instance, some of the Oricon purple gear and the few pieces that dropped during Forged Alliance allowed me to extract the mods, but they were "bound" to the equipment **slot**. In other words, mods pulled from a chest piece could only be placed in another chest piece.
Sometimes it seemed like this went away if I logged out and logged back in but I'm not sure if that was the trigger, if it was time-based, or if it was just buggy.

So ... anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the gear that dropped during the Shadow of Revan story (including solo Forged Alliances) had Armorings that were not bound to slot.  Logging in or out would not affect this.

All level 55 & 60 gear bought from Commendation vendors, as well as drops fron instances, will have Armorings/Barrels/Hilts/etc. that are bound to slot.  Nothing can get around that.

Comment: Hmm...thanks. Seems an odd system, and the interface could certainly be more descriptive. I haven't done end-game in SWTOR before though, so perhaps it makes more sense than I think.

Comment: @Japhasca I think the idea is to prevent people from using the armorings from the cheap belts/bracers so that they avoid paying for the chestpieces and such that cost more comms.

Comment: Actually they did not start to "slot bind" armorings until they decided to bind the set bonus to the armoring, in the early days the set bonus was bound to the actual gear.
So it looks like a bad side effect to me that non set bonus armorings are also bound now. this is a big problem for people who want to gear droid companions.

Comment: @Vahx True, the more important consideration is probably preventing people from farming an "easy" boss and getting a complete set bonus that way.  The droid part issue is definitely annoying, but the good news is that the top tier crafted droid parts are currently better than 198s!